# Вывести слова из списка и множества в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки, вывод, множества

1. Как вывести слова из списка и множества в Python без скобок?
   Например, из списка `['end','nend']` нужно вывести без этих скобок `[]`,
   чтобы были просто 2 слова:

   ```
   end nend
   ```

   и из множества тоже самое.
2. Как вывести данные в несколько строк?

Comment: Укажите, какая у вас версия Python (метка python-3.x была добавлена другим участником).

Answer (score 4):

Можно соединить слова в одну строку с помощью `join` с пробелом в качестве разделителя, а потом вывести:

```
words = ['end', 'nend']
print(' '.join(words))
```

Другой вариант, если просто слова нужно вывести, то можно передать список слов в `print` через "звездочку", тогда каждое слово будет передано в `print` как отдельный параметр:

```
words = ['end', 'nend']
print(*words)
```

Чтобы вывести те же слова на несколько строк, то в первом варианте просто меняем разделитель на `'\n'`:

```
words = ['end', 'nend']
print('\n'.join(words))
```

Во втором варианте нужно еще явно задать разделитель:

```
words = ['end', 'nend']
print(*words, sep='\n')
```

Вывод множества абсолютно аналогичный, т.е. меняем во всех примерах первую строку на `words = {'end', 'nend'}`, и все работает, только для множества порядок слов может меняться (для множества не гарантируется, что порядок элементов будет совпадать с первоначальным).